# Run an ASP.NET Core project with Kestrel without Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-core

I've created an ASP.NET core 2.1 project in VS2017 and run it successfully from VS2017.

The question is, What is the easiest way to run the above configuration (not production/release/deploy configuration) out of Visual Studio, on the same machine.

I can't find any exe in the project, and `dotnet run` in the project folder/output folder doesn't work.

It's best to generate an exe and click it to run.

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#how-to-use-kestrel-in-aspnet-core-apps

Comment: `dotnet run` if you are in the folder, `dotnet run src\MyApp` if you are not. `dotnet ./MyApp.dll` if its published artefacts. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?tabs=netcore21

Comment: @Tseng maybe I was in the solution folder instead of the project folder.Any way,to be clear,you should be in the folder that contains the csproj file to run "dotnet run"

Comment: The above should be `dotnet run -p src\MyApp` of course for when you are not in the project folder

Answer (score 0):

It requires a lot of preparations to run kestrel as standalone application. Checkout this sample implementation in GitHub

https://github.com/PeteX/StandaloneKestrel